# Why am I not allowed to execute this query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a user account on a Sql Server 2008 R2 database, that is member of the `db_datareader` database role and has no further permissions. Why is this user not allowed to execute the following SELECT statement?

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

And which permissions do I have to set to allow him executing this query but still prevent him from doing anything harmful to the database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to grant `VIEW DATABASE STATE` for this:

```
grant VIEW DATABASE STATE to [<YourUser>]
```

Answer (score 8):

If only there was some way to search the web that would lead you to the documentation for the product:

[sys.dm_db_partition_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187737.aspx):

> Requires VIEW DATABASE STATE permission to query the **sys.dm_db_partition_stats** dynamic management view. For more information about permissions on dynamic management views, see [Dynamic Management Views and Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188754.aspx).

and [`db_datareader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx) (okay, I'll admit this one is a *little* trickier to find):

> Members of the **db_datareader** fixed database role can read all data from all *user tables*.

*My emphasis*

Comment: Perhaps we should invent some kind of search engine for the web and get rich together ;-)

Comment: I went to google.  It brought me here -- which solved my problem.  :)